# MeshLab - Is there a paper on Vertex Attribute Transfer?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, meshlab

Is there a paper published on filter Vertex Attribute Transfer, in case there isn't can someone point me to the literature describing in detail what is happening in the background of the filter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The filter `Vertex Attribute Transfer` takes two meshes named "Source" and "Target". 
The objective of the filter is to assign values to some properties stored in the vertex of "Target", taken from the "Source" mesh.

The algorithm used here is quite clasic:

```
Foreach vertex in target_mesh:
   Find the nearest point on the surface of source_mesh [1].
   Interpolate the value of the properties on that point in source_mesh surface [2].
   Assign to target_mesh vertex the interpolated values.
```

[1] This is **not** the nearest vertex of source_mesh, but a point on the surface of source_mesh. The point is returned as the triangle index and the [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) of that point in the triangle. The process is done by iterating over every triangle in source_mesh and computing the nearest point in the triangle to a point in space. You can use an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)  or similar structure to avoid iteration over every triangle on source_mesh.

[2] Use [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Interpolation_on_a_triangular_unstructured_grid) using the 3 values defined in the vertex of triangle and the barycentric coordinates as weights.